# Spring returning 200 with no content and not hitting controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-dispatching

I have a controller as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2/**")
public class ReactController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reactEntry() {
        return "react-entry";
    }
}
```

When I log into the app and go through the login page, then navigate to the page that hits this URL, I get the content. However, if I go directly to the URL (it hits the login page but then forwards directly to this URL) spring returns a status code of 200 with a content length of 0 and my controller is never hit.

In debug logging, in the normal case I see:

```
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,805 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /v2/ reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[TRACE] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,807 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@38f60506]
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,807 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'cem' processing GET request for [/cems/v2/]
[TRACE] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,807 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@746fb8d3] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cem'
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,807 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /v2/
[TRACE] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,842 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/v2/] : [{[/v2/**],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:41:50,842 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String rest.controller.ReactController.reactEntry()]
```

However, when hit via the second mechanism, I get:

```
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:45:32,702 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /v2/ reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[DEBUG] 17 Aug 2018 10:45:32,779 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'domain.User': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager rest.domain.Personnel.entityManager
```

Notice the time gap which suggests that second line is part of a different request.

It appears that in the second case, the request is not being mapping to the cems DispatcherServlet even though it is the same URL.